# Weird thing with matlab's plotting

Tags: matlab, plot

When I execute this plot function trying to plot my data as a solid red line it will not plot anything.

```
plot(1:n, exp(x), '-r')
```

However, if I change the specification from a solid red line to a green line of circles still using the exact same data as so,

```
plot(1:n, exp(x), 'og')
```

it will plot! Why??

Here is all the code if needed.

```
clear all;
close all;

fprintf('\n\nJustin White Th-9\n\n')

x = input('Input the value of x to be approximated: ');
se = input('Input the target approximate perecent relative error, se: ');

[apre, macexp, n] = f_macexpF15(x, se);

macexp = macexp(1:end-1);

plotyy( 1:n, macexp, 1:n, apre);
hold on;
plot(1:n, exp(x), '-r')
```

And function it calls here

```
function[apre, macexp, n] = f_macexpF15(x, se)

fprintf('\nJustin White Th-9\n')

apre = 100*ones(1,3);

ms = [36 22 10];

macexp(1) = 1;
j = 1;
n = 1;
%% comments
    while apre >= se 
        macexp(j+1) = macexp(j) + x^j/factorial(j);
        apre(j) = 100 * ((macexp(j+1)-macexp(j))/macexp(j+1));
        j = j + 1;
        n = n + 1;
    end
    n = n - 1;
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Easy, `1:n` is a vector of length `n`, whereas `x` is only a scalar value if not entered correctly. So first of all check whether or not both vectors (`1:n` and `x`) are of same size. 
Why? If you have two entries for the `plot` command, and one entry is a vector and the other is a scalar, then MATLAB treats that as if you entred `n` different plot commands (`n` for the length of the vector).